# Linux kernel - Triggering evdev events from other events - binding a button to mouse click

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to develop a kernel application in order to turn a button click in an embedded board into a mouse click using software. Therefore, investigating events using 'evtest', I figured that this might be possible by simply triggering an evdev event (BTN_TOUCH, Ev Code 1) (/sys/../input/input1) from another evdev event (BTN_3, Ev Code 258) (/sys/../input/input0).

Since I am a real beginner when it comes to device driver (or kernel object) development, I would like to humbly ask for guidance as to how to start developing such an application, how to handle and trigger events using kernel modules. I hope my approach is sound and I would really appreciate any guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/philipl/evdevremapkeys -- Like the README says, this problem can be solved at different levels, and that userspace daemon seems just one of them. Seems what you need.

Comment: Another approach would be to change your driver to generate the event you need, but that needs kernel development powers -- and it not as flexible as having a daemon to remap it for you.